# Application of Game Theory in time-varying networks.

Tags: game-theory

I am a complete newbie to game theory. But I need to analyze the applicability of game theory to my work.
Considering a dynamic time-varying network where every user has different needs, my work seeks to satisfy the needs of the users such that an overall utility is maximized. Now if we consider 2 sets of users (number of users in them will vary with time), one with higher needs than the other, how do I formulate the problem in game theory?

One important point is that the users are cooperative, so no one is trying to get a greater share of the resources by harming another user. Everyone wants the total utility to be maximized.

Comment: What have you tried? As is, this question is far too vague/broad to be a good question for the site.

Comment: Tim Roughgarden and his co-authors

Comment: @DonThousand I looked for resource allocation in networks using game theory but the the results were not related. So I wanted to know if there is a specific technique or a term as such that will help me better search for it.

Comment: You can search for "distributed Nash Equilibrium Seeking", "distributed Generalized Nash Equilibrium Seeking", "distributed NE Seeking" or "distributed GNE Seeking". It isn't clear from your description what is the network for. Is the network describing the depends on each person's utility, is it a communication network or something else?